# Unable to deploy experience cloud bundle with omniscript language settings

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, experience-cloud, omnichannel

I get the following error when trying to deploy an experience cloud bundle via the metadata api to an org that has omnichannel components.

```
We couldn't validate componentAttributes in .../views/theView.json 
for component <UUID>. Error: attribute [language]: 
No omniscript language named 'English' found.. Check your file and try again.
```

The only thing I've found that hints at a possible problem is enabling multilanguage support but that's on and English is in the picklist values. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_enable_multi_language_omniscript_support_20725.htm&type=5

I'm not sure what's going wrong here so any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the real issue was the referenced omniscript metadata didn't yet exist in the org. I was leaving that for the last deployment because it doesn't like to be deployed with other metadata but the process should be:

- Deploy regular metadata - apex, custom objects & fields, etc
- Deploy Omni metadata
- Deploy experience cloud metadata